# Change the master branch in GIT

Tags: git, github

I have a "master" branch and a "master new" branch.
The "master new" is a result of a mistake that was needed to be fixed quickly.
I know it is a very bad practice to do that but thats were I am now.
For a while now I have been working as if as the "master new" is my master branch, opening branches from it etc.
My question is if there is a safe and easy way to make the "master" branch identical to the "master new" branch so I can start working with it and stop working from the "master new" branch?

Comment: You need a masterblaster, but he's off running bartertown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the below steps -

1) Delete the `master` branch from local as well as remote

2) Stay on `master new` branch and create new branch `git branch master`

3) Then run `git checkout master` This will clone all your code in `master new` branch to the newly created `master` branch

4) Now you can safely delete `master new` branch.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't push either branches, you can simply drop `master`, and rename `master_new` into `master`.

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard master_new
git branch -d master_new
```

But if you have pushed `master` already, then you could merge `master` into `master_new` (keeping `master_new` unchanged)

```
git checkout master_new
git merge -s ours master
```

Than merge `master_new` back to `master`

```
git checkout master
git merge master_new
git branch -d master_new<
git push
```

That second solution wouldn't rewrite `master`'s history, and allow you to share its new content safely with other users depending on the upstream repo.